# Installed Unable to edit registry on Windows XP Mode Virtual Machine

Tags: vb6, windows-xp, virtual-machine

I'm using the Windows XP Mode virtual machine that you get for free with Windows 7 Professional.

I'm trying to install Visual Studio for VB6 on it (not by choice), and the installation process fails.

I repeatedly get "setup has encountered a problem updating your system registry" during the "updating your system" phase.

I was going to try to run it as administrator, but I don't know the Administrator password for it.

Any ideas?

Edit:

Turns out the default account has administrator privileges, so that last bit probably wouldn't have helped anyways.

Comment: Have you tried using Process Monitor running in the VM to trace for failed registry accesses?

Answer (score 0):

VB6 doesn't work in 64 bits, does your operating system on virtual machine is 32 bits ?